# Check member functions signature in compile time

Tags: c++, templates, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write c++ template/macros to check whether two functions have the same signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541519/is-it-possible-to-write-c-template-macros-to-check-whether-two-functions-have)

Is it possible to write c++ template/macros to check whether two member functions have the same signatures (return type and arguments list) in compile time ?

I want something like this:

```
CHECK_SIGNATURES(Foo, foo, Bar, bar);
```

Compilation fails if Foo::foo and Bar::bar functions have deifferent return types or parameters list.

Comment: The same question was asked for non-member functions yesterday, the same answer applies.

Comment: Please give an example of what do you want to achieve

Comment: link to duplicate question doesn't solve match question for MEMBER function.  Solution to member match is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408881/check-that-signature-of-two-functions-or-member-function-pointer-equal

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
template <class T>
bool same(T, T) { return true; }

template <class T, class U>
bool same(T, U) { return false; }
```

Or maybe you can use `std::is_same` like in the answer to the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541544/701092).

Comment: @leemes No it checks both -- http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$758

Comment: Forget what I said. Just thought the same, thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I didn't copy this from anyone...

Comment: Make it a type trait by making it a class with a `static const bool value`. Or can this version still be used for compile-time expressions (constexpr)? What about C++03?