# Writing a template that can use a std::vector or a std::set

Tags: c++, templates

I've written an asynchronous job queue class which has been working nicely for ages.  It uses a `std::vector` as the underlying collection to keep jobs in and then processes them later as you might expect.  When I add a job it does a `push_back` on this `vector`.

Recently I decided that I wanted to templatize the underlying collection type that it uses and the with way I've written it, this should be very simple.  It's now declared thus:

```
template<typename J, typename CollectionT = std::vector<J>>
class async_jobqueue
{
public:
```

There's just one snag, for vectorish type containers I want to push things onto the end of the collection and call `push_back`, for settish type containers I'll want to call `insert`.  How can I make a compile decision about which to call?  Or is there a handy adapter I can use?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence. It blew my mind when I read it.

Comment: @SirPentor That's cool although it looks like that would give me a way of figuring it out at run time.

Comment: Either use `SFIANE`(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) or specialize or template.

Comment: @Benj You can use it in combination with `std::enable_if` or `static_asset` to do it at compile time.

Comment: @Benj How are you deciding what is a vectorish or settish type of container? Do you mean a sequence container vs. associative container?

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541519/is-it-possible-to-write-c-template-macros-to-check-whether-two-functions-have

Comment: @sftrabbit I'm not doing anything clever to decide this but I want the template to work with `std::vector`, `std::priority_queue` and `std::set`, my code is sufficiently generic I don't need to do much clever detection other than to work out whether to call push_back or insert...

Comment: `enable_if` looks promising

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the `insert(iterator, value_type)` overload and calling it with `end()`? It's available in both and should do what you want! Works on `std::list` as well!

There's really no need for type-dispatching here.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather use an overloaded helper function. The one below relies on the fact that no Standard container exposes both a single-argument `insert()` function and a `push_back()` function:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename C, typename T>
auto insert_in_container(C& c, T&& t) ->
    decltype(c.push_back(std::forward<T>(t)), void())
{
    c.push_back(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template<typename C, typename T>
auto insert_in_container(C& c, T&& t) ->
    decltype(c.insert(std::forward<T>(t)), void())
{
    c.insert(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

This is how you would use them:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;
    std::vector<int> v;

    insert_in_container(s, 5);
    insert_in_container(v, 5);

    std::cout << s.size() << " " << v.size();
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/N6QE5%2412).

Comment: Are you using `is_same` like that to induce SFINAE?

Comment: @David: Yes, that's just a trick. There could be other ways of course

Comment: Maybe you can use: `-> decltype(c.insert(std::forward<T>(t)), void())` to cut down on code bloat.

Comment: @David: Right, this is much cleaner, let me edit the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly although g++ compiles this, VC2010 says: `w32threads.h(45): error C2995: 'void insert_in_container(C &,T &&)' : function template has already been defined`

Comment: @Benj: Have you tried also the updated version of this answer?

Comment: @AndyProwl - Yes I tried both, VC2010 appears to object to multiple function templates with the same name.  I guess I could work around it by creating a template class with two overloaded functions which do the same thing....

Comment: @Benj: In that case I guess you will have to figure out another criterion for decide whether to call `insert()` or `push_back()` than just checking which one of the two expressions compile (which is what I am doing). That mostly depends on the range of types you want to support

Comment: @benj VC doesn't support much of c++11 i've heard.

Comment: @David All the c++11 features referenced in this post are available in VC2010...in theory.

Answer (score 2):

Since [concepts-lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) should hopefully be popping up in time for C++14, I might as well show you how this will be done then:

```
template<typename J, typename CollectionT = std::vector<J>>
class async_jobqueue
{
  public:

    requires Associative_container<CollectionT>()
    void adding_function(const J& item) {
      // Uses insert
    }

    requires Sequence_container<CollectionT>()
    void adding_function(const J& item) {
      // Uses push_back
    }
};
```

Of course, this is not possible yet (and may never be). However, the reception to concepts-lite is pretty positive.

Comment: Yes very, looks nice and clean.