# How to create a function pointer having a function signature, possibly at compile time

Tags: c++

I do know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541519/is-it-possible-to-write-c-template-macros-to-check-whether-two-functions-have).

But, I do not have two functions to compare, I have a function signature and a function pointer

```
template<typename T, typename ... A>
using RequiredSignature = bool(T&, A ... a);

template<typename T, typename ... A>
using RequiredFP = bool(*)(T&, A ... a);
```

Question: How do I make sure function pointer, I have received  does confirm to the required signature? At compile time.

Comment: Maybe `std::is_copy_assignable<decltype(&ok_fun), RequiredSignature<int>*>` ?

Comment: But have you tried simply changing the line in question to `required_sig* rfp; /* defines a function pointer */` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt all good ideas are simple ... let me try ..

Comment: @BenVoigt and it worketh. Too obvious to notice. Thanks.

Comment: @BenVoigt the other solution I figured is to use `std::common_type< signature, decltype(fp)> ` ... but that requires a little SFINAE number to return true if `::type` is there .. this is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is not to use template parameter deduction plus a dummy parameter, when you mean to control the type.  Just pass the type to the template parameter that wants it...

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr inline bool fp_matches_fp(U y)
{
    T* x{};
    return (sizeof(is_same_helper(x, y))) == (sizeof(yes));
}
```

You use it like

```
fp_matches_fp<required_sig>(ok_fun)
```

The caller doesn't have to create a dummy function pointer, the type trait takes care of it.  But we don't need the dummy function pointer at all...

```
template<typename T>
yes& is_compatible_helper(T*);  //no need to define it now!

template<typename T>
no& is_compatible_helper(...); //no definition needed!

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr inline bool fp_matches_fp(U y)
{
    return (sizeof(is_compatible_helper<T>(y))) == (sizeof(yes));
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

## 1

The solution is (of course) to 1. define and 2. initialize the function pointer from the given function signature.

```
    using required_sig = RequiredSignature<int>;
    /*
      actually define and initialize the required FP
     */
    required_sig* rfp{};

    if (inner::fp_matches_fp(rfp, ok_fun))
    {
        // ... MATCH ...
    }
```

Too obvious really, thanks Ben Voight.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with an explicit template parameter for the "required signature", usage would look like `fp_matches_fp<required_sig>(ok_fun)`.  Then you don't need the dummy variable or dummy function argument.

Answer (score 0):

## 2

I am adding this as "another" answer so that each one is clearer.

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/18682805/10870835
template<typename T>
class has_type
{
    typedef struct { char c[1]; } yes;
    typedef struct { char c[2]; } no;

    template<typename U> static constexpr yes test(typename U::type);
    template<typename U> static constexpr no  test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool result = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<typename SIG, typename FP >
constexpr bool signature_fp_match(FP)
{
    using c_t = common_type< SIG, FP >;
    if (has_type<c_t>::result) return true;
    return false;
}

// usage
 template<typename T, typename ... A>
using RequiredSignature = bool(T&, A ... a);

  bool ok_fun(int& ) { return true; }

  static_assert( signature_fp_match<RequiredSignature<int> >(ok_fun) ) ;
```

It is just, I thought the previous one is (much) simpler.

Answer (score 0):

## 3

Vote me down if you have too, but here is answer number 3 :) I might remove one of the previous two but having them all 3 + Bens concept & answer, gives nice chronological view.

As in my second answer, I am using `std::common_type`. This variant is just more modern and cleaner.

```
    template< class, class = void_t<> >
struct
    has_type : false_type { };

template< class T >
struct
    has_type<T, void_t<decltype(declval<T::type>())>> : true_type { };

template<typename SIG, typename FP >
constexpr inline bool signature_fp_match(FP)
{
    using c_t = common_type< SIG, FP >;

    return has_type<c_t>{}();
}
```

Here is the usage

```
    template<typename T, typename ... A>
      using RequiredSignature = bool(T&, A ... a);

bool ok_fun(int& ) { return true; }

static_assert( signature_fp_match< RequiredSignature<int> >(ok_fun) );
```

Or the less snazzy variation:

```
static_assert( signature_fp_match< bool(int&) >(ok_fun) );
```

For a more generic utility rename `signature_fp_match` to `have_common_type` or whatever you fancy.